# Removing Space between accordion panel tab header and its content?

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

Is it possible to remove the space between accordion panel tab header and the content that comes within that tab ?

[Link Here](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/accordionPanel.jsf)

In the above link, can we remove the space between the godfather-part-I and the image that appears in that tab ?

I tried this:

```
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-content {
    margin-top:10px;

}
```

But it overlaps the tab header.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Adding a `padding-top` of 0 to the `.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-content` and to the `<td>` with the images in it reduces the white space.

```
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-content {
  ...
  padding-top: 0;
}
```

If you add `border-spacing: 0;` to the table the white space is completely gone.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Padding from ".ui-accordion .ui-accordion-content" and add cellpadding="0" and cellspacing="0" in it's child table.

```
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-content{
      border-top: 0 none;
      margin-bottom: 2px;
      margin-top: -2px;
      overflow: auto;
      padding: 0;
      position: relative;
      top: 1px;
 }
```